# Split data frame to multiple data frame if column value starts with 'Table', Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have imported excel file to dataframe & it contains 4 columns and some column value starts with 'Table'.

I want to split dataframe where column value starts with 'Table'

Data Frame has below data

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Table   1   2   3
fdg 4   gfh 5
6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13
rewer   Table   14  15
16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23
24  25  Table   gfdgfd
26  27  28
```

Expected results:

df1:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Table   1   2   3
fdg 4   gfh 5
6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13
```

df2:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
rewer   Table   14  15
16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23
```

df3:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
24  25  Table   gfdgfd
26  27  28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `groupby`

```
In [113]: df1, df2, df3 = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df.eq('Table').any(1).cumsum())]

In [114]: df1
Out[114]:
    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0  Table    1    2    3
1    fdg    4  gfh    5
2      6    7    8    9
3     10   11   12   13

In [115]: df2
Out[115]:
    Col1   Col2 Col3 Col4
4  rewer  Table   14   15
5     16     17   18   19
6     20     21   22   23

In [116]: df3
Out[116]:
  Col1 Col2   Col3    Col4
7   24   25  Table  gfdgfd
8   26   27     28     NaN
```

Or

```
In [117]: dfs = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df.eq('Table').any(1).cumsum())]

In [118]: dfs[0]
Out[118]:
    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0  Table    1    2    3
1    fdg    4  gfh    5
2      6    7    8    9
3     10   11   12   13

In [120]: len(dfs)
Out[120]: 3
```

Or, Use `dict` as pointed in another answer.

Comment: can we give starts with "Table" or any string?

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.startswith('Table'))` instead of `df.eq('Table')`

Comment: @faithon.gvr.py More accurate: `x.str.startswith('Table')`

Comment: @Zero, can we export all to excel file? bcz my original data frame contains many tables inside?

Comment: Yes, and this was asked earlier, search a bit on SO/Goog.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to split the DataFrame. `np.split`'s second argument can be a list of indices indicating the locations where you wish to split. Those indices can be found with:

```
In [19]: np.flatnonzero((df == 'Table').any(axis=1))[1:]
Out[19]: array([4, 7])
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1': ['Table', 'fdg', '6', '10', 'rewer', '16', '20', '24', '26'],
    'Col2': ['1', '4', '7', '11', 'Table', '17', '21', '25', '27'],
    'Col3': ['2', 'gfh', '8', '12', '14', '18', '22', 'Table', '28'],
    'Col4': ['3', '5', '9', '13', '15', '19', '23', 'gfdgfd', np.nan]})

idx = np.flatnonzero((df == 'Table').any(axis=1))[1:]
result = np.split(df, idx)

for dfi in result:
    print(dfi)
```

prints

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0  Table    1    2    3
1    fdg    4  gfh    5
2      6    7    8    9
3     10   11   12   13
    Col1   Col2 Col3 Col4
4  rewer  Table   14   15
5     16     17   18   19
6     20     21   22   23
  Col1 Col2   Col3    Col4
7   24   25  Table  gfdgfd
8   26   27     28     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use dict comprehension and output is dictionary of `DataFrames`:

```
dfs = {k:v for k, v in df.groupby((df == 'Table').any(1).cumsum())}
print (dfs)

{1:     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0  Table    1    2    3
1    fdg    4  gfh    5
2      6    7    8    9
3     10   11   12   13, 2:     Col1   Col2 Col3 Col4
4  rewer  Table   14   15
5     16     17   18   19
6     20     21   22   23, 3:   Col1 Col2   Col3    Col4
7   24   25  Table  gfdgfd
8   26   27     28     NaN}

print (dfs[1])

    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0  Table    1    2    3
1    fdg    4  gfh    5
2      6    7    8    9
3     10   11   12   13

print (dfs[2])
    Col1   Col2 Col3 Col4
4  rewer  Table   14   15
5     16     17   18   19
6     20     21   22   23
```

And if need default index add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
dfs = {k:v.reset_index(drop=True) for k, v in df.groupby((df == 'Table').any(1).cumsum())}
print (dfs[2])


    Col1   Col2 Col3 Col4
0  rewer  Table   14   15
1     16     17   18   19
2     20     21   22   23
```

Explanation:

Check `Table` - output is boolean DataFrame

```
print ((df == 'Table'))
    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
0   True  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False
4  False   True  False  False
5  False  False  False  False
6  False  False  False  False
7  False  False   True  False
8  False  False  False  False
```

Check if at least one True per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

```
print ((df == 'Table').any(1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
dtype: bool
```

Last create groups by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print ((df == 'Table').any(1).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
8    3
dtype: int32
```